# Getting Comments to display under my post Node.js Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am attempting to implement a commenting system for articles in my node app.

Currently I can get all comments to display under the article but I want only comments that are directly related to the article to appear.

I have confirmed that they do get added to the array.

comment.js

```
const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: { type: String, required: true },
    article : { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Article' },
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }
},{timestamps: true});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

article.js

```
const ArticleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  markdown: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  createdAt: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
  },
  slug: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  },
  sanitizedHtml: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  img: {
    type: String
  },
  type:{
    type: String
  },
  comments:[{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Comment' }]
}, {timestamps: true});
```

articles.js

```
const express = require('express')
const Article = require('./../models/article')
const Comment = require('./../models/comment')
const router = express.Router()
const multer = require('multer')
const path = require('path')

router.get('/:slug', async (req, res) => {
  const article = await Article.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug })
  const comments = await Comment.find({})
  res.render('articles/show', { article: article, comments: comments });
})
```

*That solution worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `populate` like this:

```
await Article.findOne({ slug: req.params.slug }).populate("comments")
```

check the [populate documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html)